# Оптимизация функции заполнения БД

Tags: php, mysql, yii

В моем проекте есть функция, которая заполняет БД следующим образом: для каждого сотрудника создается 31 день (ну, иногда не 31, смотря сколько дней в месяце, который заполняется), дню присваиваются некоторые данные (время начала работы, продолжительность и т.д.).

Опытным путем, я выяснил, что проблема именно в "заполнении" БД "днями". Код функции:

```
public function actionCreateDays($month) {

    for($i = 1; $i <= cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month->month, $month->year); $i++) {

        $date = $month->year . '-' . sprintf("%02s", $month->month) . '-' . sprintf("%02s", $i);
        $day = Calendar::model()->findByPk($date);
        $type = $day->day_type;

        if ($type == 'Суббота' || $type == 'Воскресенье' || $type == 'Праздник') { // НУЖНО ПОДГРУЖАТЬ ПРАЗДНИКИ!!!! (ВРОДЕ ПОДГРУЖАЮТСЯ)
            $type = 'В';
        } else {
            $type = 'РАБ';
        }

        $rate_start_time = $date . ' 08:00:00';
        $rate_end_time = $date . ' 17:00:00';
        $rate_long_time  = 8;
        $rate_lunch_time = 1;

        if ($month->rate == "0,5") {
            $rate_start_time = $date . ' 17:15:00';
            $rate_end_time = $date . ' 21:15:00';
            $rate_long_time  = 4;
            $rate_lunch_time = 0;
        } elseif ($month->rate == "0,25") {
            $rate_start_time = $date . ' 21:30:00';
            $rate_end_time = $date . ' 23:3.:00';
            $rate_long_time  = 2;
            $rate_lunch_time = 0;
        }

        $day = new GraphDays();
        $day->month_id = $month->id;
        $day->day = $i;
        $day->type = $type;
        $day->start_time = $rate_start_time;
        $day->end_time = $rate_end_time;
        $day->long_time  = $rate_long_time;
        $day->lunch_time = $rate_lunch_time;
        $day->save(false);

        $day = new TimesheetDays();
        $day->month_id = $month->id;
        $day->day = $i;
        $day->type = $type;
        $day->start_time = $rate_start_time;
        $day->end_time = $rate_end_time;
        $day->long_time  = $rate_long_time;
        $day->lunch_time = $rate_lunch_time;
        $day->save(false);

    }
}
```

Принимаются любые советы по оптимизации этого ужаса =(

**Дополню ответ**. Вот функция создания месяца в БД, которая вызывает функцию выше (создания дней).

```
public function actionCreateMonth($arg_year, $arg_month) {

    $depart = Departs::model()->find(array('condition' => 't.name = "' . Yii::app()->user->getId() . '"'));

    $start = microtime(true);

    $s = new Soap();
    $all_posts = $s->getPosts();
    $all_divisions = $s->getDivisions();

    $all_rates = $s->getRelatedActualyPersons($depart['uid']);

    $rates_time = microtime(true) - $start;
    $start = microtime(true);

    $cache = array();

    foreach ($all_rates as $rate) {

        $month = Months::model()->findByAttributes(array(
            'person_post' => $all_posts[$rate['post']],
            'person_uid' => $rate['uid'],
            'type' => $rate['empType'],
            'rate' => $rate['rate'],
            'month' => $arg_month,
            'year' => $arg_year
        ));

        if ($month == null) {

            $month = new Months();
            $month->depart_uid = $rate['depart'];
            $month->depart_name = $all_divisions[$rate['depart']]['name'];
            $month->person_uid = $rate['uid'];
            $month->person_tab = $rate['tabNum'];
            $month->person_fio = $rate['fio'];
            $month->person_post = $all_posts[$rate['post']];
            $month->rate = $rate['rate'];
            $month->type = $rate['empType'];
            $month->year  = $arg_year;
            $month->month = $arg_month;
            $month->graph = 8;
            $month->categorie = "Служащие";
            $month->save(false);

            $this->actionCreateDays($month);

            // Подсчет времени
            if (!array_key_exists($month->rate, $cache)) {
                $cache[$month->rate] = array(
                    "graphInfo" => $this->calculateTotal($month, 'graph'),
                    "tabelInfo" => $this->calculateTotal($month, 'tabel')
                );
            }

            $time = new TotalTimeGraph();
            $time->month_id = $month->id;
            $time->days = $cache[$month->rate]['graphInfo']['total_days'];
            $time->hours = $cache[$month->rate]['graphInfo']['total_hours'];
            $time->night_hours = $cache[$month->rate]['graphInfo']['night_hours'];
            $time->normal_hours = $cache[$month->rate]['graphInfo']['normal_hours'];
            $time->deviation_hours = $cache[$month->rate]['graphInfo']['deviation_hours'];
            $time->save(false);

            $time = new TotalTimeTimesheet();
            $time->month_id = $month->id;
            $time->days = $cache[$month->rate]['tabelInfo']['total_days'];
            $time->hours = $cache[$month->rate]['tabelInfo']['total_hours'];
            $time->night_hours = $cache[$month->rate]['tabelInfo']['night_hours'];
            $time->normal_hours = $cache[$month->rate]['tabelInfo']['normal_hours'];
            $time->deviation_hours = $cache[$month->rate]['tabelInfo']['deviation_hours'];
            $time->holiday_hours = $cache[$month->rate]['tabelInfo']['holiday_hours'];
            $time->days_15 = $cache[$month->rate]['tabelInfo']['days_15'];
            $time->hours_15 = $cache[$month->rate]['tabelInfo']['hours_15'];
            $time->night_hours_15 = $cache[$month->rate]['tabelInfo']['night_hours_15'];
            $time->holiday_hours_15 = $cache[$month->rate]['tabelInfo']['holiday_hours_15'];
            $time->save(false);
        }
    }

    $bd_time = microtime(true) - $start;

    return array(
        '1c_exec_time' => $rates_time,
        'bd_exec_time' => $bd_time
    );
}
```

Логика ее работы просто - создаем запись для сотрудника, вызываем функцию создания дней для только что созданной записи.

Comment: а в чем проблема-то? Долго работает? Или неправильно? Или что? Если долго, то можно сохранять порциями (например, по 100 штук за раз), тогда лишнее время на обработку запроса тратиться не будет

Comment: Само собой, долго работает. Порциями не вариант сохранять, т.к. работа возможно только после полного сохранения данных.

Comment: Есть такое значение - NULL. То есть пустое множество. Типовая информация, например, сотрудник1 работал в рабочий день, так же как сотрудник2 тоже работал в этот рабочий день - это пустая трата дискового пространства. С тем же успехом можно заполнять базу данных сплошными NULL. Разве нет?

Comment: Вы там переиспользуете соединение, надеюсь? Или на каждый `$day->save(false);` создаётся соединение новое?

Comment: @Suvitruf если честно, я не знаю. Сейчас попробую разобраться с соединением.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics я понял о чем ты, здравая идея, конечно, но не представляю возможным, как сейчас можно изменить рабочую базу, чтобы прийти к такой архитектуре.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов Тут нечего смотреть с точки зрения оптимизации. Основной рабочий код который пишет в базу тут не представлен. С другой стороны если этот цикл пишет в базу всего 31 запись то тут тормозить нечему. И я уверен на 80%, что что бы там ни писалось на самом деле, при наличии информации о праздниках в базе все это можно проинсертить по одному запросу на таблицу, а не городить огород на php

Comment: @Mike записывается 31 день для 150 сотрудников, в две таблицы. Т.е. получается 9300 вставок.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов Я в приведенном коде не вижу сотрудников. надо же видеть как именно insert происходит. И такие вещи действительно лучше делать одним запросом. Я подозреваю, что там просто вся таблица сотрудников помножается на 31 день и для всех пишется одно и то же. при том, что в не приведенных тут частях небось по одной записи по очереди вставляется

Comment: @Mike я дополнил ответ, добавив еще одну функцию, из которой вызывается проблемная. Хотя я уже не знаю, может они обе проблемные...

Comment: @ИльяБизунов Ну вышестоящая точно ничего не даст. тут до сотрудников вообще не добрались, ни в одной из них. по крайней мере я не вижу. сотрудники небось где то в save только появляются

Comment: Почему, все здесь. Сейчас объясню.

Comment: @Mike 
Получаем список сотрудников:
`$all_rates = $s->getRelatedActualyPersons($depart['uid'])`
Далее, если месяц для этого сотрудника еще не создан, создаем его:
`foreach ($all_rates as $rate) {

$month = Months::model()->findByAttributes(array(
    'person_post' => $all_posts[$rate['post']],
    'person_uid' => $rate['uid'],
    'type' => $rate['empType'],
    'rate' => $rate['rate'],
    'month' => $arg_month,
    'year' => $arg_year
));`

Comment: @Mike, http://pastebin.com/0JnkLVjE

Comment: @ИльяБизунов Боле менее разобрался... Проблема в том, что с точки зрения php тут оптимизировать особо нечего. Ваша модель работает по одному сотруднику, всегда. По другому она не может. Хотите быстро - отказывайтесь от использования всего этого вороха классов и делайте одним запросом к БД, напрямую

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы используете ActiveRecord там, где он вам по сути не нужен.
Для создания записей внутри `actionCreateDays` лучше сначала создать массив необходимых данных, а затем поместить его в базу одним insert запросом.

Также в этой функции используется `$day = Calendar::model()->findByPk($date);`.

Проблемы в этом вызове:

- Запрос не кешируется
- По сути вы используете только `day_type` - значит и тут ActiveRecord не нужен, а достаточно простого запроса
- День ищется каждую итерацию, хотя можно до цикла запросить все `day_type` для всех доступных Calendar одним запросом с условием `where id in (...)`.

Итог - вы экономите кол-во запросов(1 вместо 30 для 30-дневного месяца), память(dao вместо activerecord) и лишние миллисекунды за счет отказа от activerecord.

Аналогичную оптимизацию можно провести в функции `actionCreateMonth`.

PS: Вместо замеров времени через microtime в yii есть [встроенный простой профайлинг](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#beginProfile-detail):

`Yii::beginProfile('MyLongOperations');
// тут какие-нибудь долгие операции
Yii::endProfile('MyLongOperations');`

PPS: В плане оптимизации этой задачи можно пойти ещё дальше и использовать хранимые процедуры MySQL, а также сделать расчет коэффициентов на лету.